# Back icon state change

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

When keyboard is open, the icon of the back button is changed to indicate that clicking it will close the keyboard instead of going back.

Back button:

[image]

Close button:

[image]

Is there a way how to switch from the back icon to close icon programmatically without actually opening the keyboard? We are using a custom keyboard implementation and would like to have the similar behaviour to the native one.

Comment: If there is a way I don't think it would be an easy one. Probably involve some native calls. You better look android source code yourself.  Anyway what I'm wondering is, the usual way to implement custom keyboard is opening a PopupWindow over the Soft Keyboard (well, at least last time I checked it was), so soft keyboard should already done than that for you.

Comment: @Onur Nice suggestion, didn't know about this trick, but unfortunately the keyboard is part of a web application, that is displayed using WebView (so it's cross-platform).